# IE11 issue removing password field - bug or expected behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I came across a weird issue today when removing password fields from the DOM in IE11. This fiddle should hopefully show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/eaxp2Lre/2/

The relevant part is where I'm removing the password input element using the following approach:

```
var passwordField = document.getElementById('password-field'),
    div = document.createElement('div');

div.appendChild(passwordField);    
div.innerHTML = '';
```

(I'm aware this is an odd way of removing a node from the DOM, but it's how our current JS framework does it internally - I will probably override this to use `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`)

The odd behaviour is that, upon setting the innerHTML of the div to an empty string, the selection in `window.getSelection()` gets populated with a range containing a single textNode, with the value of whatever had been typed into the password field.

Has anyone else come across this? Is there a reason for this, or is it just a bug? It's one of the weirdest examples of IE behaviour I've seen in a while..

Comment: could you check that `passwordField.parentElement` is `null` after doing `div.innerHTML = '';` ? `passwordField` may still exist in the DOM

Comment: @Pudge601 `getSelection `  method does not return the selection if the selected content is within an `input:password`, `input:text or textarea `element  [Source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvonpc.php). So after making `div.innerhtml` i presume that selection rangecount still exists

Comment: @Hacketo The parentElement is indeed null. What's interesting is that the node which contains the contents of the passwordField is actually a text node that seems to have been created by IE when the contents of the temporary div are removed.

Comment: @Webruster I'm not actually interested in getting the selection for the input; what this is showing is that IE11 seems to be setting the selection to a text node containing the password field's contents when the input element is removed. I have absolutely no idea why it would be doing this...

Comment: @Pudge601 Here is an article it state that they have created `div` and without any content to the `div` on making the `innerhtml` to empty . it is appearing empty space.. could be similar to the your case i guess !! here [take a look](http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/empty-div-takes-up-space-after-setting-innerhtml-to-blank)